# Missing project.assets.json when running Publish Vs2019

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, msix

When trying to create a 64 bit MSIX package using the Publish command in a VS 2019 WPF packaging project,
we are getting the following error 'wappublish\win-x64\project.assets.json' not found... Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file'.

The packaging project itself builds fine and can be debugged. Running 'dotnet restore' from the package manager console does not help. We have noticed there is no win-x64 directory created under wappublish.

We are using VS 2019 16.7.4 Community Edition. Anyone any ideas what could cause this.

Thanks

Comment: Wow 2 years old and no-one. I now have this problem as well. Anyone with a solution

Comment: I'm using VS2022 17.3.3 and target win-x64. I'm also seeing a MSB4018 The "ResolvePackageDependencies" task failed unexpectedly. It also says "Invalid framework version '10.0.19041/win10-x64' 
Hmmm is the the win10-x64 =<> win-x64 issue like (https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues/1015) that was fixed in 16.10.4 but that issue was related to winUI

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I'm also having the same problem